# C# Powershell code not executing on Windows 7

Tags: c#, powershell

Powershell code executed through my C# application is executing perfectly on Windows 10, but won't even run on Windows 7. Neither does it get beyond Process.WaitForExit()

I've tried using Powershell (System.Management.Automation) itself inside the code.
I've also set 'set-executionpolicy remotesigned' and it runs using a powershell script (.ps1), but not when using it in my C# code as shown below.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                string pdfName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - new FileInfo(fileName).Extension.Length) + ".pdf";

                sw.WriteLine("$Exl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application");
                sw.WriteLine("$Doc = $Exl.Workbooks.Open(\"" + fileName + "\")");
                sw.WriteLine("$Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType]::xlTypePDF, \"" + pdfName +"\")");
                sw.WriteLine("$Doc.Close($False)");
                sw.WriteLine("[gc]::Collect()");
                sw.WriteLine("[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()");
                sw.WriteLine("$Exl.Quit()");
                sw.WriteLine("[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Exl)");
                sw.WriteLine("Remove-Variable Exl");
            }
        }
        p.WaitForExit();
```

On Windows 10, the script successfully converts an Excel file to pdf, but on Windows 7 - the script doesn't even open Excel to convert the file.

Comment: I'm curious why you're invoking powershell to do that instead of just using Excel interop directly.

Comment: What version of `System.Management.Automation` have you linked to in the project? By default Windows 7 only has PowerShell v2; if you referenced a later assembly that might be why it never runs.

Comment: maybe can catch exception to see the issue?

Comment: @itsme86 I'm asking myself the same question. It works, thank you.

Only thing is, i'm still wondering why the powershell script is executing fine on Win10 but not on Win7?

Comment: I'm glad it works. Not sure about the Win7 powershell problem. Is @briantist onto something maybe?

Comment: This PowerShell script requires Office (Excel) to be installed. Did you have that on Windows 7?

Comment: @briantist, I've linked the assembly from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll" on my Windows 10 machine, since that's the environment I'm programming on. Not sure if this would help, but the timestamp of the Digital Signatures indicate "Tuesday, 23 October 2018".
I will try it out now using the assembly I can get from the Windows 7 machine.

Edit: Just checked. The path "...Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\" does not exist on Windows 7.

Comment: @LexLi yes I have.

Comment: @IanN Great. You linked a PowerShell 5.1 assembly, but you're trying to use it on a box that only supports PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: What version of PowerShell is the Windows 7 machine running? `$PSVersionTable`